# Consulta JDBC sql server

Tags: java, sql-server

Tengo una duda respecto a un sistema de java que funcionaba originalmente con *MySQL*, la situación es que dicha base de ese sistema fue migrada a SQL server y mi pregunta es si el código utilizado en la parte de java para el procesamiento de datos puede funcionar para *SQL* server adjunto ejemplos de métodos y verificar si pueden funcionar de forma adecuada en la nueva base de datos (ya tengo el driver respectivo para *SQL SERVER*) agradecería si pueden resolver mi duda gracias.

Hasta el momento no he intentado conectar nada solo quiero estar seguro antes de poder intentar cualquier cosa.

```
public class UsuariosBD {

    private Usuarios Usuario;

    public UsuariosBD() {
    }

    public UsuariosBD(Usuarios Usuario) {
        this.Usuario = Usuario;
    }

    public Usuarios getUsuario() {
        return Usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(Usuarios Usuario) {
        this.Usuario = Usuario;
    }

    public void Crear() {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (Nombre, NombreUsuario, Correo, TipoUsuario, Activo, Contrasena) VALUES ('" + Usuario.getNombre() + "', '" + Usuario.getNombreUsuarios() + "', '" + Usuario.getCorreo() + "', '" + Usuario.getTipoUsuario() + "', " + Usuario.isActivo() + ", '" + Usuario.getContrasena() + "')";
        Conexion con = new Conexion(sql, false);
        con.EjecutarSQL();
    }

    public ResultSet Listado() {
        String sql = "SELECT idUsuarios, Nombre, NombreUsuario, Activo FROM usuarios ORDER BY NombreUsuario;";
        Conexion con = new Conexion(sql, true);
        con.EjecutarSQL();
        return con.getResultado();
    }

    public ResultSet Consulta() {
        String sql = "SELECT idUsuarios, Nombre, NombreUsuario, Correo, TipoUsuario, Activo, Contrasena FROM Usuarios WHERE idUsuarios = " + this.Usuario.getIdUsuarios() + ";";
        Conexion con = new Conexion(sql, true);
        con.EjecutarSQL();
        return con.getResultado();
    }

    public void Editar() {
        Usuarios u = this.Usuario;
        String sql = "UPDATE usuarios SET Nombre='" + u.getNombre()+ "', NombreUsuario='" + u.getNombreUsuarios()+ "', Correo='" + u.getCorreo()+ "', TipoUsuario='" + u.getTipoUsuario()+ "', Activo=" + u.isActivo() + ", Contrasena='" + u.getContrasena()+ "'  WHERE idUsuarios = " + u.getIdUsuarios()+ ";";
        Conexion con = new Conexion(sql, false);
        con.EjecutarSQL();

    }
    
    public void Eliminar() {
        String sql = "DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE idUsuarios = " + this.Usuario.getIdUsuarios()+ ";";
        Conexion con = new Conexion(sql, false);
        con.EjecutarSQL();
    }
    
    public ResultSet Autenticar() {
        String sql = "SELECT IdUsuarios FROM usuarios WHERE NombreUsuario = '" + this.Usuario.getNombreUsuarios()+ "' AND Contrasena = '" + this.Usuario.getContrasena()+ "'";
        Conexion con = new Conexion(sql, true);
        con.EjecutarSQL();
        return con.getResultado();
    }
}
```

Clase para realizar conexión:

```
package datos;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;

/**
 *
 * @author Juan M
 */
public class Conexion {

    private String sql;
    private boolean EsperaResultado;
    private ResultSet Resultado;

    public String getSql() {
        return sql;
    }

    public void setSql(String sql) {
        this.sql = sql;
    }

    public boolean isEsperaResultado() {
        return EsperaResultado;
    }

    public void setEsperaResultado(boolean EsperaResultado) {
        this.EsperaResultado = EsperaResultado;
    }

    public ResultSet getResultado() {
        return Resultado;
    }

    public void setResultado(ResultSet Resultado) {
        this.Resultado = Resultado;
    }

    public Conexion() {
    }

    public Conexion(String sql, boolean EsperaResultado) {
        this.sql = sql;
        this.EsperaResultado = EsperaResultado;
    }

    public void EjecutarSQL() {
        try {
            Connection cnx = null;
            Statement sta = null;
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            cnx = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/wiki?user=wiki&password=123456&useSSL=false");
            sta = cnx.createStatement();
            if (EsperaResultado) {

                Resultado = sta.executeQuery(sql);

            } else {

                sta.executeUpdate(sql);
                sta.close();
                cnx.close();

            }

            //sta.close();
            //cnx.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String error = e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Las consultas que muestras deberían funciona en SQL Server. En todo caso, si hubiera cosas más complejas (como SP u otros) sería cuestión de actualizar ese código. Otra cosa que sí es importante cambiar es la cadena de conexión: `jdbc:mysql://localhost/wiki?user=wiki&password=123456&useSSL=false` la cual es diferente para cada SGBD. Y finalmente, desde JDBC 4, no es necesario el uso de `Class.for.Name()`

Comment: No sabia lo del class for name lo de cambiar la cadena si ya tenía conocimiento, solo quería una segunda opinión acerca de esas consultas muchas gracias por aclararme la duda

Comment: Como son consultas simples no debería de haber problemas, el problema viene cuando utilizas funciones propias de la base de datos por ejemplo: obtener la fecha en MySQL es CURDATE() y en SQLServer es GETDATE(), la sintaxis general de SQL es la misma para todas la base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

toma en cuenta que las consultas SQL son casi iguales en mysql, sqlserver, postgres, sqlite, ect. La gran diferencia es la programación SQL ya que los procedimientos almacenados son diferentes en ambos SGDB's

Answer (score 0):

Prácticamente vas usar el mismo código, debido a que haces uso de consultas DDL (Create, Alter, Drop).
Personalmente prefiero usar `PreparedStatement`  en lugar de `Statement` y si voy usar procedimientos almacenados el `CallableStatement`.
Las razones por la que prefiero el `PreparedStatement`:

1. Amplía la interfaz de `Statement` . Tiene métodos para vincular varios tipos de objetos , incluidos archivos y matrices.
2. Protege contra la inyección de SQL.
3. Utiliza una compilación previa, esto acelera la comunicación entre la base de datos y la JVM. Entre otras cosas.

Entonces si vas hacer uso de consultas `DML` es mejor usar `PreparedStatement`.

Cuando realizas una actualización a la base de datos `Insert` `Update` haz uso del `commit` y el `rollback`, esto es importante en cualquier programa que interactúa con la base de datos.